# Android Bluetooth Device Locator

Tags: android, dictionary, bluetooth

How can I locate other BlueTooth devices that are using my app and show them on map, with range, exact location, like radar map.

Comment: @Naskov Did you implemented it ??

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could possibly do this is if your Bluetooth slave devices individually have the ability to track and report their location (e.g. GPS).

Otherwise it's not possible at all. The Bluetooth radio and antenna in your Android device will have no direction finding ability.

Answer (score 1):

Possible design idea :

You want to implement this with the help of a webservice.

Make your app **report** its being used(may be you want to report at regular intervals and shutdown of app) along with location information (probably you want to use GPS, have a look at this : [Obtaining User Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)).

Make you *radar app* to read those information and prepare the map.

Cons :

1. Availability of GPS will affect your application
2. Accuracy is limited.

Comment: The point is to be without GPS, cause there is no GPS reception in some places. It must go strictly via BlueToot.

Comment: @Naskov OMG there is no way by which you can get location via bluetooth!